# How to import Visual Paradigm Business Diagram into Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I created a Business Diagram (BPNM 2.0) in Visual Paradigm, and I would like to import it into Draw.io.
I am able to export the Diagram in a .xml file using the facility Export to BPMN 2.0, but when I import the file into Draw.io, the result is not at all what expected.

Any idea how to import it correctly?
Below there is sample of the .xml file as exported from Visual-Paradigm.
Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions exporter="Visual Paradigm" exporterVersion="1" id="Definition" targetNamespace="http://www.omg.org/bpmn20" xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100501/BPMN20.xsd">
    <process id="_4" isExecutable="false" name="Business Process Diagram1">
        <documentation textFormat="text/html">&lt;html&gt;&#10;  &lt;head&gt;&#10;    &lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;&#10;      &lt;!--&#10;        body { color: #000000; font-family: Dialog; font-size: 12px }&#10;      --&gt;&#10;    &lt;/style&gt;&#10;    &#10;  &lt;/head&gt;&#10;  &lt;body&gt;&#10;    &lt;p&gt;&#10;      &#10;    &lt;/p&gt;&#10;  &lt;/body&gt;&#10;&lt;/html&gt;&#10;</documentation>
        <task completionQuantity="1" id="BP861" isForCompensation="false" name="Task" startQuantity="1">
            <incoming>BP865</incoming>
        </task>
        <startEvent id="BP862" name="Trigger">
            <outgoing>BP864</outgoing>
        </startEvent>
        <userTask completionQuantity="1" id="BP863" implementation="##unspecified" isForCompensation="false" name="UserTask" startQuantity="1">
            <incoming>BP864</incoming>
            <outgoing>BP865</outgoing>
        </userTask>
        <sequenceFlow id="BP864" name="" sourceRef="BP862" targetRef="BP863"/>
        <sequenceFlow id="BP865" name="" sourceRef="BP863" targetRef="BP861"/>
    </process>
    <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="diagram-_4" name="Business Process Diagram1">
        <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="_4" id="plane-_4">
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="BP861" id="ID_33257445_0345_3203_2240_076027600072">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="142" width="261" x="276" y="301"/>
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="BP862" id="ID_73257445_0345_3203_2240_076027600073">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="66" width="71" x="90" y="140"/>
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="BP863" id="ID_73257445_0345_3203_2240_076027600074">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="135" width="261" x="276" y="106"/>
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="BP864" id="ID_07257445_0345_3203_2240_076027600075">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="161" y="173"/>
                <omgdi:waypoint x="275" y="173"/>
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="BP865" id="ID_07257445_0345_3203_2240_076027600076">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="411" y="241"/>
                <omgdi:waypoint x="411" y="300"/>
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
        </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
    </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Comment: any chance you can share the XML?

Comment: @user0 I copied a the .xml file into the question (see above).

Answer (score 1):

draw.io doesn't support BPMN import at this moment, so feel free to vote and track this feature request [here](https://trello.com/c/qTy8dqTx/36-bpmn-import).

​draw.io supports creating BPMN from scratch using templates and shapes.

The details can be found [here](https://about.draw.io/creating-different-types-of-flowcharts-with-draw-io/).
And you can start creating a diagram using this [link](https://www.draw.io/?libs=bpmn).